# adding and filling a property to existing Core Data entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

So, many times before when I needed to add a property to an entity, I created a new version of xdatamodel file and performed lightweight migration, that automatically added this property to all already existing NSManagedObjects.

But now i need no only to add property, but also to fill it with a value, that can be calculated using another existing property.(Ex: I have an entity User with property "name", and now I need to add a property "hashname" = [user.name base64],so that all my existing users have this filled property)

So, is there a way to do it using migration? (I know that it's possible simply select all users without hashname and fill it manyally after lightweigt migration, but i want to know if migration technology provided by apple can do it for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it "manually". The only automatic filling of a property is with a default value, but that would not be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually add calculated properties to the model. Just create an NSManagedObject subclass that includes this property and calculates it from its other attribues.